# Input de Dados - ListView

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, excel-vba

Bom dia galera!

Bom, eu criei um formulário de atualização de dados com a visualização por um listview!

Eu coloco o valor no textbox, clico na linha desejada e clico em
 alterar e o valor no **listview** é alterado porém na folha do excel não
 está sendo alterada, alguém pode me explicar o porque ? irei deixar o
 código aqui.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Call Alterar

End Sub

Sub Alterar()

ListView1.LabelEdit = lvwManual

    With ListView1


        .SelectedItem.SubItems(3) = TxtPrevisto.Text
        .SelectedItem.SubItems(4) = TxtRealizado.Text


    End With


End Sub
```

Comment: Você quer alterar na célula da planilha Excel? Você precisa criar um código que altere a célula desejada

Comment: Então, não sei como fazer, pode me ajudar nisso ? eu no caso clico na linha desejada e ele ja altera o valor na celula desejada no listview, porém na planilha excell ele nao faz isso.

Comment: Utilize a propriedade [Range.Cells](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/office/vba/api/excel.range.cells) ou somente `Range` para escrever na planilha. Há vários tutoriais e respostas no SOpt sobre isso.